# How to use an environment variable inside a quoted string in Bash

Tags: bash, quotes, environment

I've tried various forms of the following in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
svn diff $@ --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff -x "-y -w -p -W $COLUMNS"
```

But I can't get the syntax to correctly expand the `COLUMNS` environment variable.

I've tried various forms of the following:

```
svn diff $@ --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff -x '-y -w -p -W $COLUMNS'
```

and

```
svn diff $@ --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff -x '-y -w -p -W ${COLUMNS}'
```

and

```
eval svn diff $@ --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff -x "-y -w -p -W $COLUMNS"
```

Suggestions?

Comment: so what do those examples produce in your case? And what do you want them to produce?

Comment: the command outside the script is working?

Comment: Have you tried `svn diff $@ --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff -x "-y -w -p -W ""$COLUMNS"`

Comment: BTW, using `$@` unquoted makes it exactly the same as `$*` -- which is to say that it breaks `"foo bar"` into two separate arguments, `foo` and `bar`. If you want to preserve the original argument list just as it was given to you, you want `"$@"`.

Comment: See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If unsure, you might use the 'cols' request on the terminal, and forget COLUMNS:

```
COLS=$(tput cols)
```

Answer (score 533):

Just a quick note/summary for any who came here via Google looking for the answer to the general question asked in the title (as I was).  Any of the following should work for getting access to shell variables inside quotes:

```
echo "$VARIABLE"
echo "${VARIABLE}"
```

Use of single quotes is the main issue.  According to the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes):

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (`'`) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>   [...]
>   Enclosing characters in double quotes (`"`) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of `$`, `` ` ``, `\`, and, when history expansion is enabled, `!`. The characters `$` and ` retain their special meaning within double quotes (see Shell Expansions). The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: `$`, `` ` ``, `"`, `\`, or newline. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of these characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters without a special meaning are left unmodified. A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an `!` appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the `!` is not removed.
>   The special parameters `*` and `@` have special meaning when in double quotes (see Shell Parameter Expansion).

In the specific case asked in the question, $COLUMNS is a special variable which has nonstandard properties (see lhunath's answer above).

Comment: In the case of single quotes, maybe this workaround helps: 
`'before'"$variable"'after'` (as stated in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13802438/2254346)

Comment: Great answer! I had the same issue of referring my env variable within single quotes. Once I changed my single quote to double quotes, my env variable was being expanded as expected.

Answer (score 16):

Note that `COLUMNS` is:

1. **NOT** an environment variable.  It is an ordinary bash parameter that is set by bash itself.
2. Set automatically upon receipt of a `SIGWINCH` signal.

That second point usually means that your `COLUMNS` variable will only be set in your *interactive* shell, **not** in a bash script.

If your script's `stdin` is connected to your terminal you can manually look up the width of your terminal by asking your terminal:

```
tput cols
```

And to use this in your SVN command:

```
svn diff "$@" --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff -x "-y -w -p -W $(tput cols)"
```

(Note: you should *quote* `"$@"` and stay away from `eval` ;-))

Answer (score 7):

Another approach towards keeping single quotes itself
in that case you can just wrap around your variable in single quote instead of how you would usually do with double quotes

```
X='abc'
>echo 'preceeding text ---"${X}"---- succeesing text'
preceeding text ---"${X}"---- succeesing text
>echo 'preceeding text ---"$X"---- succeesing text'
preceeding text ---"$X"---- succeesing text
>echo 'preceeding text ---'$X'---- succeesing text'
preceeding text ---abc---- succeesing text
>echo 'preceeding text ---'${X}'---- succeesing text'
preceeding text ---abc---- succeesing text
```

Answer (score 2):

The following script works for me for multiple values of `$COLUMNS`.  I wonder if you are not setting `COLUMNS` prior to this call?

```
#!/bin/bash
COLUMNS=30
svn diff $@ --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff -x "-y -w -p -W $COLUMNS"
```

Can you echo `$COLUMNS` inside your script to see if it set correctly?

Comment: Boo, hiss re: unquoted `$@` -- that splits a single parameter `"two words"` up into two separate parameters, `two` and `words`. Should be `"$@"` to pass the argument list through exactly as it was given.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right, so I guess something else is at fault (not export-ing COLUMNS ?).

A trick to debug these cases is to make a specialized command (a closure for programming language guys). Create a shell script named diff-columns doing:

```
exec /usr/bin/diff -x -y -w -p -W "$COLUMNS" "$@"
```

and just use

```
svn diff "$@" --diff-cmd  diff-columns
```

This way your code is cleaner to read and more modular (top-down approach), and you can test the diff-columns code thouroughly separately (bottom-up approach).

Comment: The commandline is parsed before the process is forked, so not exporting COLUMNS can not be the problem.

Comment: He says his code in part of a bash script, thus it can be the problem.