# How to use sed command with space using muliple ssh

Tags: shell, ssh, sed

My command:

```
ssh -q user@node1  ssh -q user@node2 ssh -q user@node3 'sed -i 's/'"aa bb"'/'"dd ee"'/g' file-path'
```

Error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command

Need help to resolve this.

Comment: Please ask your sysadmin or ask at [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does bash deal with nested quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941394/how-does-bash-deal-with-nested-quotes)