# bash command syntax with options with double quotes in variables

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a aws command to update the cache control metadata for one file:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/file.js s3://mybucket/file.js --region us-east-1 --acl public-read --metadata-directive REPLACE --cache-control "public, max-age=86400"
```

However, I want to run this command against multiple selected files. So I went ahead to make this command reusable:

```
bucket="s3://mybucket"
region="us-east-1"
updateflag="--region $region --acl public-read --metadata-directive REPLACE --cache-control \"public, max-age=86400\""

aws s3 cp $bucket/fileA.js $bucket/fileB.js $updateflag
```

But this does not work ! It gives `Unknown options: max-age=86400"` error.

I've tried a few ways around double quotation marks but the only time it works is like this:

```
updateflag="--region $region --acl public-read --metadata-directive REPLACE"
cacheflag="public, max-age=86400"
aws s3 cp $bucket/em.js $bucket/em.js $updateflag --cache-control "$cacheflag"
```

What went wrong when I get all options in one variable only ?

### UPDATE:

Thanks for pointing out duplicated questions.

I found this question answers my question: [Why does shell ignore quotes in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables)

I ended up doing the following:

```
set_cache_control () {
  updateflag=(--region $region --acl public-read --metadata-directive REPLACE --cache-control '"public, max-age=86400"')
  aws s3 cp $bucket/$1 $bucket/$1 "${updateflag[@]}"
}

set_cache_control fileA.js
set_cache_control fileB.js
```

```

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) Short summary: use a function or array, not a plain variable. Do *not* use `eval`.

Comment: More generally, when you want to re-use a command, define a function. `aws_update () { aws s3 cp "$2" "$3" --region "$1" ...; }`. Call like `aws_update us-east-1 "s3://mybucket/file1" "s3://mybucket/file2" `.

Comment: Concerning the update: It looks like you're using two levels of quotes around the cache-control string; don't do this, since the inner quotes will be treated as part of the data. Also, I recommend using a function OR an array, not both. Once you're using a function, the array is a useless complication.

Answer (score 0):

Bash is separating `--cache-control \"public, max-age=86400\"` into `--cache-control` `"public,` and `max-age=86400"`. So it is not parsing the quotes like you think. Rather, it is passing another argument to the command, which then the `aws` cli does not know how to handle.

Since Bash is as complicated as it is, and there are a plethora of ways to format strings. You can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941394/how-does-bash-deal-with-nested-quotes) dealing with nested quotes in bash.