# Properly quote bash alias definition

Tags: bash, alias

I have the following command that I am trying to put into a bash alias.  The command by itself works fine, but when I try to alias it, I am getting the following errors:

The Command

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "$(find "{}" -type f | wc -l)" {}' \; | sort -nr
```

The Alias

```
alias csfiles='find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "$(find "{}" -type f | wc -l)" {}' \; | sort -nr'
```

The Error:

```
-sh: alias 0: not found
-sh: alias {} \; | sort nr: not found
```

I think this means I am not using quotes right but I am having trouble determining the correct combo.  Help?

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with aliases but I think your alias is too complex. I believe alias is just used to shorten one command with arguments, i.e. `alias l='ls -al'`. You may need to create a function `csfiles`. But it has been a while so I may be mistaken.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941394/how-does-bash-deal-with-nested-quotes

Comment: I second creating a bash function to do this. You would call it the same way, with the benefit of being able to pass arguments if needed.

Comment: As written, the `find` command will fail for certain file names (such as those containing double quotes). Don't try to embed `{}` in the command; only use it as an argument to `sh`. `sh -c '....' _ {}`. Wherever you used `{}`, use `$1`.

Comment: @chepner that's a very good point!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your outer `find` doesn't do anything you couldn't do with a simple glob. This eliminates a layer of quotes (along with the `sh` process for each directory found).

```
# Ignoring the issue of assuming no file name contains a newline
for d in ./*/; do
   echo "$(find "$d" -type f | wc -l) $d"
done
```

Just define a shell function to eliminate the second layer imposed on the argument to `alias`.

```
csfiles () {
  for d in ./*/; do
    echo "$(find "$d" -type f | wc -l) $d"
  done
}
```

The remaining call(s) to `find` can also be replaced with a `for` loop, eliminating the problematic assumption of one line per file name:

```
csfiles () {
  for d in ./*/; do
    echo "$(for f in "$d"/*; do [ -f "$f" ] && echo; done | wc -l) $d"
  done
}
```

You could keep `find` if it supports the `-printf` primary, because you don't care about the actual names of the files, just that you get exactly one line of output per file.

```
csfiles () {
  for d in ./*/; do
    echo "$(find "$d" -type f -printf . | wc -l) $d"
  done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quotes around the definition, like this:

```
alias foo="find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'echo \"\$(find \"{}\" -type f | wc -l)\" {}' \; | sort -nr"
```

Every literal `"` inside the definition gets escaped: `\"`.

Note: You also need to escape the inner command substitution to prevent it from getting expanded upon alias definition time. Like this `... \$(...)`

---

As a follow up on chepners comment, you should pass the filename to the inner find command as an argument. Otherwise you will run into problems if one of your folders has a name with a `"` in it:

```
alias foo="find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'echo \"\$(find \"\${1}\" -type f | wc -l) \"\${1}\" \"' -- \"{}\" \; | sort -nr"
```