# Replacing text with sed

Tags: shell, replace, sed

I have in my file a line of this kind

```
    integer, parameter ::  L = 2   !Size of the system
```

Where the number `2` can be any integer number. I want to find this line using `sed` and replace the value of the number with another one.

I tried:

```
$ L=5
$ sed -i '/L = /c\integer, parameter ::  L = $L   !Size of the system' moduleselfcons.f90
```

but in my modified file I have at the end:

```
integer, parameter ::  L = $   !Size of the system
```

and not:

```
integer, parameter ::  L = 5   !Size of the system
```

What is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expansion of variable inside single quotes in a command in bash shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variable-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash-shell-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`).

But I think you can shorten the expression:

```
L=5
sed "s/L = [0-9]*/L = $L/" file
```

If it is your desired output add the `-i` flag for in-place editing.

Comment: @user3368447 the `!` has to be esacped try it with `\!` and the double quotes.