# I want to append to a line number using sed

Tags: sed

I have a file that I need to append to certain lines.

I can get the line numbers and have been able to use sed to print the entry but not to append the entry.

All I need to do is something like

```
sed -n '$VAR s/$/,nosuid/' > to_file
```

Just can not get the syntax down.

Thank you.

Comment: Shell variables do not expand in single quotes. Assuming `$VAR` is a shell variable you need to use double quotes around it. `"$VAR s/$/,nosuid/"` or `"$VAR"' s/$/,nosuid/'` or similar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expansion of variable inside single quotes in a command in bash shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variable-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
 sed "$VAR s/$/,nosuid/" > to_file
```

Like Etan Reisner said in the comments, the quotes should be double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed -n $VAR's/$/,nosuid/' > to_file
```