# Double quote as parameter in SQLPLUS

Tags: shell, unix, sqlplus

So I want to include in a shell script a sqlplus command, the problem is that one of the parameters could be a double quote char (") but sqlplus thinks is the start of a string.

This is the command:

```
sqlplus username/ @file.sql " /home/myuser/Desktop/
```

I already enclosed them in: single quote, double single quote, double quote, double double quote. Also tried to escape the char using `\` but nothing works.

The most I'm getting is that it waits me to close the 'string' or the following error:

```
string beginning "" /home/my..." missing terminating quote (").
```

Comment: I don't understand your double-quote. However, you can try a here-document construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick

```
sqlplus username/ @file.sql "'\"'" /home/myuser/Desktop/
```

Useful resources at:

[UNIX Shell Quotes - a simple tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html#uh-0)

[Expansion of variable inside single quotes in a command in bash shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variable-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash-shell-script#answer-13802438)