# Using $1 in regexp within a Makefile

Tags: regex, perl, makefile

I try to do a replace with following perl command:

```
perl -C -p -i -e 's/([\?\.\!])\n/$1 /g' html/數14.html
```

The result is fine when I call it from the command line. When I call it from within a Makefile it doesn't work. Apparently the $1 is interpreted as shell variable.

In the Makefile it looks like this:

```
數14.html: 數14.adoc 40_2064_Im\ Strand-Appartment.adoc 41_2064_Ein\ Plan.adoc  42_1915_In\ einer\ Suppenküche.adoc 
    asciidoctor -D html parts/數14.adoc  
    perl -C -p -i -e 's/([\?\.\!])\n/$1 /g' html/數14.html
```

How can I have normal regexp behaviour here?

Comment: Please show how you are invoking it in your bash script. It will not be a shell variable if it is single-quoted, as in your example above; but it will if you put some different quotes around it. For example, `foo=$(perl -C -p -i -e 's/([\?\.\!])\n/$1 /g' html/數14.html)` is quoted by `$()`, which will expand `$1`, and you'd need to escape `$1` into `\$1`.

Comment: Read this thread: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557677/how-to-pass-a-regular-expression-as-a-parameter-to-a-perl-one-liner-in-a-bash-sc/31563152#31563152]

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's not a bash script, it's a Makefile. :-|

Comment: Please avoid XY-questions. The answer is *very* different for Makefiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makefiles always interpret `$` sequences before executing commands, disregarding any quoting. In order to escape `$` in a Makefile, write it as `$$` - that will result in a single `$` in the command.