# Variable expansion within posix-extended regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, find

I've been trying to add a user-defined file extension into a regex with no success. Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter which file extension are you looking for: "

read fExt

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '^./q[0-9]{1,2}[a-z]?.\"$fExt\"$'
```

The file names I'm looking for look like

```
q1.txt
q22b.pdf
q3c.JPG
```

This version doesn't work so I've been using multiple `ext1|ext2|...` cases, which obviously isn't modular. How would I add `$fExt` into my `-regex` input? Is it possible in the first place, or is there an easier way to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expansion of variable inside single quotes in a command in bash shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variable-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash-shell-script)

Comment: And even if it's not an exact duplicate: that's the problem.

Comment: yep that post was exactly what I was looking for, despite looking for it for awhile. cheers @BenjaminW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've used single-quotes prevents $fExt from being expanded.

Assuming a bash-like shell, the regex you seem to want could be specified as follows:

```
"^q[0-9]{1,2}[a-z]?\.$fExt\$"
```

or

```
$'^q[0-9]{1,2}[a-z]?\\.'"$fExt"'$'
```