# Why do this regular expression used with sed result in a parse error?

Tags: regex, sed, zsh

I'm trying to use `sed` to replace `'version' => '1.2.3',` with `'version' => '1.2.4',`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
echo " 'version' => '1.2.3', " | sed -E 's/([\s]*[\"\']version[\"\'][\s]*=>[\s]*[\"\'])[-_a-zA-Z0-9\.]+([\"\'][,]?)/\11.2.4\2/'
```

Here's what my shell tells me:

```
zsh: parse error near `)'
```

I've tried the same regex (minus the replacement part) on some online regex testers and it seems to work there. So why doesn't it work when I use it with `sed`?

Comment: Maybe it is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variable-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash-shell-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't backslash a single quote in single quotes. In zsh, you can use `''` to put a single quote into single quotes, or use the more portable `'\''` (tested in both bash and zsh):

```
echo " 'version' => '1.2.3', " \
| sed -E 's/(\s*[\"'\'']version[\"'\'']\s*=>\s*[\"'\''])[-_a-zA-Z0-9\.]+([\"'\''],?)/\11.2.4\2/'
```

I also changed `[\s]` into `\s` and `[,]` into `,` as they are equivalent but the latter is simpler.

Comment: Yes, and `[,]?` = `,?`

Comment: Thank you! In the end I used this: `sed -E "s/^(\s*[\"']version[\"']\s*=>\s*[\"'])[-_a-zA-Z0-9.]+([\"'],?\s*)$/\1${NEW_VERSION}\2/"`

Comment: The `''` feature works only if the option `RC_QUOTES` is enabled, which is not the case by default. You can enable it with `setopt rcquotes`.

Comment: @Adaephon: Weird, it seems to be enabled on OpenSUSE.