# bash shell pass variable and quotes

Tags: bash, variables, quotes

I've a variable, wich contains all types of characters

```
myvar="alfanum;001String"
```

and I need to pass them to a command with a single quotes in this way

```
java -jar myapp.jar  HERE I NEED TO PUT ->  'alfanum;001String' with single quotes
```

but if I do

```
java -jar myapp.jar "'$myvar'"
```

it doesn't work.

Note I can't use just double quotes:

```
java -jar myapp.jar "$myvar"
```

because `$myvar` is a user's input and myapp.jar need to retrieve it rounded with a single quotes

Thank you

Comment: Quite related: [Expansion of variable inside single quotes in a command in bash shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13799789/1983854). So something like `java -jar myapp.jar ''"$var"''` should do

Comment: Your first code with `"'$myvar'"` should work.

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, otherwise I would not opened this question :)

Comment: What doesn't work and what is error?

Comment: If the *argument* needs to contain single quotes, it's the caller's responsibility to provide the correct data, not yours. If you weren't using `myvar`, would the correct call be `java -jar myapp.jar 'alfanum;001String'` or `java -jar myapp.jar "'alfanum;001String'"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
java --jar myapp.jar $(echo "'$myvar'")
```

But why not just use double quotes?

Comment: The command substitution needs to be quoted, but in `bash`, this is exactly the same as `java -jar myapp.jar "'$myvar'"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can mix several quote types together to form a string in singe quotes:

`"'""$myvar""'"` will expand to `'alfanum;001String'`. You're probably need just `"$myvar"` here though.