# How to print current date saved in a variable in an echo sentence for shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell

Below is the output I am getting and also what I want as an output

---

```
$ date

Wed Apr 11 08:41:35 UTC 2018

$ DATE=date 

$ $DATE    

Wed Apr 11 08:41:43 UTC 2018         

$ echo 'TEST'           

TEST                       

$ echo 'Today is $DATE'    

Today is $DATE       

$ echo Today is $DATE   

Today is date
```

--> wanted output as : **Today is Wed Apr 11 08:41:43 UTC 2018**

Comment: DATE=$(date); echo "Today is $DATE"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let analyse step by step what you have done. At the bottom I give you several way how to achieve what you want.

**Step by step:**

```
$ date
Wed Apr 11 08:41:35 UTC 2018
```

Here, you just executed the `date` command. Nothing more, nothing less.

```
$ DATE=date
$ $DATE
Wed Apr 11 08:41:43 UTC 2018
```

In this part you stored the word `date` into the variable `DATE`. Next you execute the variable `DATE` as a command. As `DATE=date` you essentially just execute the `date` command.

```
$ echo 'TEST'
TEST
```

You successfully printed the word `TEST` on `/dev/stdout`.

```
$ echo 'Today is $DATE'
Today is $DATE
```

Here the fun starts. You try to print the content of `DATE` in a string. However you make use of single quotes `'`. Inside single quotes everything is preserved literally, without exception. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variable-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash). This expalains why there is no parameter expansion going on and you print `$DATE` and not `date`.

```
$ echo Today is $DATE
Today is date
```

In this case there is parameter expansion going on. The parameter `DATE` contains the word `date`, so this is what you get. There is no command executed as this is not what you asked for.

**So how can we achieve the wanted output?**

What you are interested in is what is called *command substitution*. Command substitution can be achieved with `$(command)` or `` `command` ``.  Bash performs  the expansion of any of these two forms by executing `command` and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted. This gives us the following options :

```
$ DATE=$(date)
$ echo "Today is $DATE"
```

or

```
$ echo "Today is $(date)"
```

Finally, you can use the `date` command directly:

```
$ date "+Today is %c"
```

Answer (score 0):

In shell script if you want to store the output of a command you have to execute the command first and that command should be right hand side of `=` sign. When a command executes its outputs to standard output stores into the variable. Now see below:-

```
DATE=$(date)  or DATE=`date`
```

Now in the above, date command will execute on the right hand side of `=` and its output to standard output will be stored in variable `DATE`.

Hope this will help you.