# Replace line containing variables and space by bash commands

Tags: bash, sed, replace, space

I have some files containing lines, some of them are similar that shown below:

```
HETATM 2340  C2  2FN     1      15.566  27.839  11.677  1.00 24.33           C
```

I need to replace

```
2FN     1
```

to

```
2FN D   1
```

so that the final result is:

```
HETATM 2340  C2  2FN     1      15.566  27.839  11.677  1.00 24.33           C
```

This is rather easy by using sed command and in the case of you always have the same words to replace

```
sed 's/2FN     1/2FN D   1/g' input.file > output.file
```

However, in the case one wants to use variables

```
A="2FN"
B="1"
```

in sed command, the result is not what is expected, I suppose due to the multiple spaces in the text to replace.

I tried several ways, such as:

```
A="2FN"
B="1"
S='     '
G=$(echo "$LIG${S}$LIGN")
sed 's/$G/2FN D   1/g' input.file > output.file
```

But no expected result has been obtained.
Interestingly, by echo G variable is:

```
"2FN     1"
```

but sed doesn't replace to

```
"2FN D   1"
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: try `sed "s/$G/2FN D   1/g" ...`

Comment: Not sure you define the `G` correctly, but you are not using the variable inside single quotes. If you want to use a variable inside a string, use double quotes, `"s/$G/2FN D   1/g"`

Comment: Actually, I never used the double quotes. In this way it works. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to get `bash` to resolve variables within single quotes.  Single quotes are telling `bash`: "Don't resolve anything in here, take it literally as is"

If you simply replace the single quotes in your sed command with double quotes, as @oguzismail suggested, you'll be fine.

Much more detail, if needed, is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13802438/236528

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the double quotes suggested by @oguzismail. Actually, it works  by using that . Thanks again