# Unable to use Variable inside curl

Tags: bash, curl

I have a JSON file inside a variable.

```
echo $JSON
{"name": "jkslave1", "nodeDescription": "This is a test agent", "numExecutors": "1", "remoteFS": "/root", "labelString": "jenkins", "mode": "NORMAL", "": ["hudson.slaves.JNLPLauncher", "hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy$Always"], "launcher": {"stapler-class": "hudson.slaves.JNLPLauncher", "$class": "hudson.slaves.JNLPLauncher", "workDirSettings": {"disabled": false, "workDirPath": "", "internalDir": "remoting", "failIfWorkDirIsMissing": false}, "tunnel": "", "vmargs": ""}, "retentionStrategy": {"stapler-class": "hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy$Always", "$class": "hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy$Always"}, "nodeProperties": {"stapler-class-bag": "true"}, "type": "hudson.slaves.DumbSlave", "Jenkins-Crumb": "6af50cfe57d4685d84cc470f311fa559"}
```

And I want to use the variable inside my `curl` command like this

```
curl -k -X POST "https://<JENKINS-URL>/computer/doCreateItem?name=jkslave1&type=hudson.slaves.DumbSlave" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-H "Jenkins-Crumb: ${CRUMB}" \
-d 'json=${JSON}'
```

But the above implementation gives me the ERROR

```
Caused: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to parse JSON:${JSON}
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.getSubmittedForm(RequestImpl.java:1022)
at hudson.model.ComputerSet.doDoCreateItem(ComputerSet.java:296)
```

I tried the following too

```
-d 'json="${JSON}"'
```

and also

```
-d 'json=\"${JSON}\"'
```

But it doesnt seem to work.

How can I send the JSON body to my curl command saved as a variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply

```
curl ... -d "json=$JSON"
```

Answer (score 1):

variables don't work within single quotes.

Inside single quotes everything is preserved literally, without exception.

This is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variable-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash)

Try double quotes how you used it in the line before