# abyss-pe: variables to assemble multiple genomes with one command

Tags: linux, bash, abyss

How do I rewrite the following to properly replace the variable with my genomeID? (I have it working with this method in Spades and Masurca assemblers, so it's something about Abyss that doesnt like this approach and I need a work-around)

I am trying to run abyss on a cluster server but am running into trouble with how abyss-pe is reading my variable input:

1. my submit file loads a script for each genome listed in a .txt file
2. my script writes in the genome name throughout the script
3. the abyss assembly fumbles the variable replacement

Input.sub:

```
queue genomeID from genomelisttest.txt
```

Input.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
genomeID=$1
cp /mnt/gluster/harrow2/trim_output/${genomeID}_trim.tar.gz ./
tar -xzf ${genomeID}_trim.tar.gz
rm ${genomeID}_trim.tar.gz
for k in `seq 86 10 126`; do
    mkdir k$k
    abyss-pe -C k$k name=${genomeID} k=$k lib='pe1 pe2' pe1='../${genomeID}_trim/${genomeID}_L1_1.fq.gz ../${genomeID}_trim/${genomeID}_L1_2.fq.gz' pe2='../${genomeID}_trim/${genomeID}_L2_1.fq.gz ../${genomeID}_trim/${genomeID}_L2_2.fq.gz' 
done
```

Error that I get:

```
`../enome_trim/enome_L1_1.fq.gz': No such file or directory
```

This is where "enome" is supposed to replace with a five digit genomeID, which happens properly in the earlier part of the script up to this point, where abyss comes in.

Comment: `pe1='../${genomeID}_trim/${genomeID}_L1_1.fq.gz ...'` - `${genomeID}` is probably not replaced due to single quote. You may need double quote for shell replacement (if that is what you want).

Comment: ive tried it also with "$genomeID" and gotten the same results. Do you mean that I should try pe1="..."

Comment: [Expansion of variable inside single quotes in a command in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13799789/608639), [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/608639), etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pe1='../'"$genomeID"'_trim/'"$genomeID"'_L1_1.fq.gz ...'
```

I added a single quote before and after the variable