# expand variable inside single quotes shell script

Tags: shell

I need to be able to use `${var}` with preserving the single quote as the command requires it.
I have tried escaping the single quote by concatenating `'"${var}"'` but the command gave error as the single quotes didn't get preserved.

```
$COMMAND '[{"name": "john", "tel": ${var}}]'
```

Comment: Very detailed explanation to a near duplicate problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variables-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

You should quote this except for "${var}".

```
var=999
$COMMAND '[{"name": "john", "tel": "'${var}'"}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your command does not "require" single quotes around that JSON
string. It's a shell that requires them to treat the entire JSON
string as a single word and pass it to `$COMMAND`.

There are 2 ways to use it in JSON string (I set `var` to 999):

```
$ echo command "[{\"name\": \"john\", \"tel\": ${var}}]"
command [{"name": "john", "tel": 999}]
```

or:

```
$ echo command '[{"name": "john", "tel": '"${var}"'}]'
command [{"name": "john", "tel": 999}]
```

However, if your command really requires JSON string enclosed in single quotes do this:

```
"'[{\"name\": \"john\", \"tel\": ${var}}]'"
```

Also, `[` and `]` might not be needed:

```
"{\"name\": \"john\", \"tel\": ${var}}"
```

Comment: yes i have tried both for using the double quotes it won't work as the command gives parse error the command requires the array to be quoted in single qotes, when i concatenated the variable `'"${var}"'` i lost the single quotes so i got the parse error, i want to be able to preserve the single quotes and use the variable

Comment: to work it need to be exactly `command '[{"name": "john", "tel": 999}]' `without the single quotes a parse error results

Comment: Would that `"'[{\"name\": \"john\", \"tel\": ${var}}]'"` be ok?

Comment: `error: Error parsing JSON:'[{"name": "john", "tel": ".0680000"}]'` though the single quotes was preserved but i got the same parse error

Comment: Well, I have no idea what your command is doing. Can you post it here? And why does your tel. starts with `.`, shouldn't it be a number?

Comment: After a little thinking - it might be because this is not correct JSON. Try removing `[` and `]`.

Comment: `[ ]` is for an array in JSON, how is that not correct?

Comment: @BenjaminW.: You're course right, it's correct. We'd need to see command that OP uses.