# Commenting a pull request in a GitHub action

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to get a regular comment inserted in a pull request from a GitHub action. I can't seem to get it right. [Octokit, the underlying library, allows you to create *reviewComments* to PRs](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/#octokit-routes-pulls-create-comment), but those refer to a commit and that's not what I want, I want a simple comment. I figured I can just use `octokit.issues.createComment`. However, that does not seem to work.
Here's the code

```js
import * as core from '@actions/core';
const {GitHub, context} = require('@actions/github')
const parse = require('parse-diff')

async function run() {
    try {
        // get information on everything
        const token = core.getInput('github-token', {required: true})
        const github = new GitHub(token, {} )
        console.log( context )
        const PR_number = context.payload.pull_request.number

        // Check if the body contains required string
        const bodyContains = core.getInput('bodyContains')

        if ( context.payload.pull_request.body.indexOf( bodyContains) < 0  ) {
            core.setFailed("The body of the PR does not contain " + bodyContains);
            console.log( "Actor " + context.actor + " pr number " PR_number)
            const result = await github.issues.createComment({
                owner: context.actor,
                repo: context.payload.repository.full_name,
                issue_number: PR_number,
                body: "We need to have the word " + bodyContains + " in the body of the pull request"
            });
            console.log(result)
       } // more irrelevant stuff below
}}
```

This simply seems to retur "Not found". I can't seem to be able to find out if it's a type problem, or something different. Theoretically, owner, repo, and issue number, as well as body, should be right, and it's printed correctly. Any help will be appreciated. This is probably a more general question in the realm of GitHub API, with GitHub actions being simply the context, so I might be wrong there.

Comment: I had a similar need and wanted a bot-like comment inserted by GitHub Actions. I'm going to shamelessly share my repo, which I managed to do the trick with axios and REST call - some example PR and issue are in the repo: https://github.com/rytswd/respost/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in 2024 this is how it worked for me:

```
name: My name example
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, edited, synchronize, reopened]

jobs:
  comment-in-pr:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
      pull-requests: write
      repository-projects: write
      id-token: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: ' Thanks for reporting!'
            })
```

Answer (score 82):

A canonical way is using the official [Github Script actions](https://github.com/actions/github-script#comment-on-an-issue). Don't get confused, issues and PRs are the same for the GitHub API.

**EDIT 2023:** (V6)

V6 is out, here's how to use it. No breaking changes, just the script version has changed.

```yaml
on:
  # Trigger the workflow on push or pull request
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - develop

jobs:
  comment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: ' Thanks for reporting!'
            })
```

---

**EDIT 2021:** (V5)

Adapting to GH's newer versions, one has to reference the rest client directly. See [note as of writing](https://github.com/actions/github-script/tree/0c6f00768732ed1187947a986d58800c44dfed88#breaking-changes-in-v5).

```yaml
on:
  # Trigger the workflow on push or pull request
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - develop

jobs:
  comment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/github-script@v5
        with:
          github-token: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: ' Thanks for reporting!'
            })
```

---

**2020:** (V3)

```yaml
on:
  # Trigger the workflow on push or pull request
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - develop

jobs:
  comment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/github-script@v3
        with:
          github-token: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
          script: |
            github.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: ' Thanks for reporting!'
            })
```

Seen on: https://github.com/actions/github-script#comment-on-an-issue

Comment: I don't like this 2020 approach. Touching real API endpoints with `curl` should be the way to do it. Otherwise, this all github actions thingie is useless as a script, as it uses another "script", thus obscuring the intent and jeopardizing itself. As a result, making you dumb, cause you don't know (or have control over, rather) what's going on.

Comment: @SevastyanSavanyuk OP's wording could have been less opinionated, but once you are in the GH ecosystem, I think wanting to be less dependent on it is kind of not necessary. Having worked a lot with actions, this is the best way to go imo

Comment: As for "Don't get confused, issues and PRs are the same for the GitHub API.", check https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/main/packages/github/src/context.ts#L55-L62

Comment: hello @kevin-goedecke, the 6th version of actions/github-script is now available, you should update your snippet

Comment: Shouldn't this be triggered by `pull_request_target` instead of `pull_request`? In a run triggered by `pull_request`, `GITHUB_TOKEN` doesn't have write access to the repository and causes the error 'Resource not accessible by integration'.

Comment: @DavidLechner yes we are having this issue - 'Resource not accessible by integration' what is the solution here?

Comment: My answer doesn't have may votes yet, so it is farther down the page. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71683208/1976323

Comment: @Kay I recently solved the 'Resource not accessible by integration' issue from a PR. You need to add the `pull_requests: write` permission to your GitHub workflow. Examples can be found here:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs

Comment: @wjkw1: it seems to be `pull-requests: write` with a hyphen, rather than an underscore?

Comment: @sam-w Yes you're correct! Use a hyphen folks, not an underscore: e.g. `pull-requests: write`

Answer (score 32):

I initially tried to use [Respost](https://github.com/rytswd/respost/), but it doesn't allow setting a raw `body` string.

So here's a way to do it with `curl`.

In a `.github/workflows/whatever.yml`:

```yaml
name: Some workflow

on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  comment:
    if: contains(github.event.comment.body, 'special string')

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Add comment to PR
        env:
          URL: ${{ github.event.issue.comments_url }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          curl \
            -X POST \
            $URL \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
            -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
            --data '{ "body": "blah blah" }'
```

Comment: For the event `pull_request` I had to use `${{ github.event.pull_request.comments_url }}` for the URL

Comment: for help with string substitution see here for single/double quotes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variables-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the [`@actions/github`](https://github.com/actions/github) which will permit you to use an [octokit client](https://octokit.github.io/) to simplify the actions :

```js
const core = require('@actions/core');
const github = require('@actions/github');

async function run() {
  try {
    const message = core.getInput('message');
    const github_token = core.getInput('GITHUB_TOKEN');

    const context = github.context;
    if (context.payload.pull_request == null) {
        core.setFailed('No pull request found.');
        return;
    }
    const pull_request_number = context.payload.pull_request.number;

    const octokit = new github.GitHub(github_token);
    const new_comment = octokit.issues.createComment({
        ...context.repo,
        issue_number: pull_request_number,
        body: message
      });

  } catch (error) {
    core.setFailed(error.message);
  }
}

run();
```

*Taken from this [repo](https://github.com/thollander/actions-comment-pull-request/).*

Comment: Here's a demo as standalone workflow: [workflow.yml](https://github.com/cirosantilli/china-dictatorship/blob/97408314e85673e20c10c1232de8d46f8cdd6004/.github/workflows/issue.yml), [main.js](https://github.com/cirosantilli/china-dictatorship/blob/97408314e85673e20c10c1232de8d46f8cdd6004/action.js). But yeah, just use `actions/github-script` most likely: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64126737/895245

Answer (score 9):

The other answers don't mention is the security restrictions of a GitHub action run from a fork that triggers the `pull_request` event. The `GITHUB_TOKEN` in these actions does not have write access to the repository and therefore cannot create a comment. See [permissions for the GITHUB_TOKEN](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token).

The [GitHub docs for the workflow_run event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) have a good example of how to work around this. The basic idea is to have the workflow that is triggered by the `pull_request` event upload any info needed in the comment as a build artifact using [actions/upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact). Then a separate workflow triggered by a `workflow_run` event downloads the information using [actions/download-artifact](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact).

NOTE: For security, since the workflow triggered by `workflow_run` has write access, it must be **committed to the default branch** before it can be used. (Also keep in mind that the build artifacts could contain malicious data from a malicious pull request).

Here is a copy of the example workflows from the linked docs (in case the link breaks or the docs change):

```yaml
name: Upload data

on:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  upload:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:        
      - name: Save PR number
        env:
          PR_NUMBER: ${{ github.event.number }}
        run: |
          mkdir -p ./pr
          echo $PR_NUMBER > ./pr/pr_number
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: pr_number
          path: pr/
```

```yaml
name: Use the data

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [Upload data]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  download:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Download artifact'
        uses: actions/github-script@v5
        with:
          script: |
            let allArtifacts = await github.rest.actions.listWorkflowRunArtifacts({
               owner: context.repo.owner,
               repo: context.repo.repo,
               run_id: context.payload.workflow_run.id,
            });
            let matchArtifact = allArtifacts.data.artifacts.filter((artifact) => {
              return artifact.name == "pr_number"
            })[0];
            let download = await github.rest.actions.downloadArtifact({
               owner: context.repo.owner,
               repo: context.repo.repo,
               artifact_id: matchArtifact.id,
               archive_format: 'zip',
            });
            let fs = require('fs');
            fs.writeFileSync(`${process.env.GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/pr_number.zip`, Buffer.from(download.data));

      - name: 'Unzip artifact'
        run: unzip pr_number.zip

      - name: 'Comment on PR'
        uses: actions/github-script@v5
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            let fs = require('fs');
            let issue_number = Number(fs.readFileSync('./pr_number'));
            await github.rest.issues.createComment({
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              issue_number: issue_number,
              body: 'Thank you for the PR!'
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

I like the GitHub action [Comment Pull Request](https://github.com/thollander/actions-comment-pull-request#comment-pull-request---github-actions) very much, because it allows for updating comments.

Example for adding a comment:

```yaml
- name: Comment PR
  uses: thollander/actions-comment-pull-request@v2
  with:
    message: |
      Hello world ! :wave:
    reactions: eyes, rocket
```

Updating a comment is done via "tags" (which render as "hidden" HTML elements)

```yaml
- name: Comment PR with execution number
  uses: thollander/actions-comment-pull-request@v2
  with:
    message: |
      _(execution **${{ github.run_id }}** / attempt **${{ github.run_attempt }}**)_
    comment_tag: execution
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what works for me, when I want to comment on a PR from a **push** event (not **pull_request** event, where it's easy):

```
      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: (await github.rest.repos.listPullRequestsAssociatedWithCommit({
                commit_sha: context.sha,
                owner: context.repo.owner,
                repo: context.repo.repo,
              })).data[0].number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: ' Thanks for reporting!'
            })
```

The key part is this, which allows to get the right "issue number" for a PR:

```
await github.rest.repos.listPullRequestsAssociatedWithCommit({
                commit_sha: context.sha,
                owner: context.repo.owner,
                repo: context.repo.repo,
              })).data[0].number
```

Answer (score 1):

You need write permission to your job for this, this worked for me. Taken inspiration from another comment -

```
stage_test:
    permissions: write-all
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps:
    - name: Check out code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2 
    - name: Comment PR
      uses: thollander/actions-comment-pull-request@v2
      with:
        message: |
          Test successful !
        reactions: rocket
```