# How to find Bidirectional Unicode control characters in git repo?

Tags: git, unicode

I have a package on NPM that shows that it contain "Bidirectional unicode control characters" reported by [socket.dev](https://socket.dev/npm/package/jquery.terminal).

I've found answer to this question [How to update GitHub Actions CI to detect Trojan Code commits (malicious [bidirectional] unicode chars, python)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70086236/387194).

I've used:

```sh
git grep -oP "[^\x00-\x7F]*"
```

It found some matches in binary files, so I've removed all binary flags from .gitattributes and now I only have files from `__tests__` directory that has ANSI files and one image, but those are not published to NPM.

What is a proper way to find those: "Bidirectional unicode control characters"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `perl` one liner

```sh
perl -CSD -ne 'print "$ARGV: $_" if /\p{Bidi_Control}/' file1 file2 ...
```

will print out lines of the given UTF-8 encoded files that have bidirectional control characters in them.

Unfortunately, PCRE, which `git grep -P` uses, doesn't support anywhere near the level of unicode properties that perl regular expressions do. You can search for the control characters explicitly, though:

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal.git
$ cd jquery.terminal
$ git grep -IP '(*UTF)[\x{061C}\x{200E}\x{200F}\x{202A}-\x{202E}\x{2066}-\x{2069}]'
js/jquery.terminal-src.js:        "&lrm;": "<U+200E>",
js/jquery.terminal-src.js:        "&rlm;": "<U+200F>",
```

The `-I` option skips binary files.

(List of control characters taken from [perluniprops](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops)).