# Preserve '\n' newline in returned text over ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, opensuse

If I execute a find command, with grep and sort etc. in the local command line, I get returned lines like so:

```
# find ~/logs/ -iname 'status' | xargs grep 'last seen' | sort --field-separator=: -k 4 -g
0:0:line:1
0:0:line:2
0:0:line:3
```

If I execute the same command over ssh, the returned text prints without newlines, like so:

```
# VARcmdChk="$(ssh ${VARuser}@${VARserver} "find ~/logs/ -iname 'status' | xargs grep 'last seen' | sort --field-separator=: -k 4 -g")"
# echo ${VARcmdChk}
0:0:line:1 0:0:line:2 0:0:line:3
```

I'm trying to understand why ssh is sanitising the returned text, so that newlines are converted to spaces. I have not yet tried output'ing to file, and then using scp to pull that back. Seems a waste, since I just want to view the remote results locally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you echo the variable `VARcmdChk`, you should enclose it with `"`.

```sh
$ VARcmdChk=$(ssh ${VARuser}@${VARserver} "find tmp/ -iname status -exec grep 'last seen' {} \; | sort --field-separator=: -k 4 -g")
$ echo "${VARcmdChk}"
last seen:11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88:99:00
last seen:00:99:88:77:66:55:44:33:22:11
```

Note that I've replaced your `xargs` for `-exec`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the question is a duplicate of this one, [Why does shell Command Substitution gobble up a trailing newline char?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17747/why-does-shell-command-substitution-gobble-up-a-trailing-newline-char), so partly answered.

However, I say partly, as the answers tell you the reasons for this happening as such, but the only clue to a solution is a small answer right at the end.

The solution is to quote the echo argument, as the solution suggests:

```
# VARcmdChk="$(ssh ${VARuser}@${VARserver} "find ~/logs/ -iname 'status' | xargs grep 'last seen' | sort --field-separator=: -k 4 -g")"
# echo "${VARcmdChk}"
0:0:line:1
0:0:line:2
0:0:line:3
```

but there is no explanation as to why this works as such, since assumption is that the variable is a string, so should print as expected. However, reading [Expansion of variable inside single quotes in a command in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variable-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash) provides the clue regarding preserving newlines etc. in a string. Placing the variable to be printed by echo into quotes preserves the contents absolutely, and you get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The `echo` of the variable is why its putting it all into one line. Running the following command will output the results as expected:

```
ssh ${VARuser}@${VARserver} "find ~/logs/ -iname 'status' | xargs grep 'last seen' | sort --field-separator=: -k 4 -g"
```

To get the command output to have each result on a new line, like it does when you run the command locally you can use `awk` to split the results onto a new line.

`awk '{print $1"\n"$2}'`

This method can be appended to your command like this:

```
echo ${VARcmdChk} | awk '{print $1"\n"$2"\n"$3"\n"$4}'
```

Alternatively, you can put quotes around the variable as per your answer:

`echo "${VARcmdChk}"`