# Double quotes inside double quotes bash script

Tags: bash, ssh

Can anyone help me get the following bash script working with double quotes (see difference between ${PATH_TO_RELEASES} with and without double quotes)?

```
function run() {
  OUTPUT=$(ssh -T "${USER}@${HOST}" eval "$@")

  EXIT_CODE=$?
  if [ "${EXIT_CODE}" -ne 0 ]; then
    exit 1;
  fi

  echo "${OUTPUT}"
}
```

This works:

```
run "
  COUNT_RELEASES=\$(find ${PATH_TO_RELEASES}/releases/* -maxdepth 0 -type d | wc -l)
  echo \${COUNT_RELEASES}
"
```

This doesn't work (see double quoting/escaping). It throws the following error messages: **find: /path/to/releases/releases/*: No such file or directory**

```
 run "
  COUNT_RELEASES=\$(find \"${PATH_TO_RELEASES}/releases/*\" -maxdepth 0 -type d | wc -l)
  echo \${COUNT_RELEASES}
"
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variable-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash) might help

Comment: Read [Bash FAQ 050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: It did help, thanks a lot.