# AMBARI + how to set value in json REST API

Tags: json, bash, api, ambari

the following API example , will `stop` the `kafka` service in `ambari`

```
export service=kafka

curl -u admin:admin -i -H 'X-Requested-By: ambari' -X PUT -d '{"RequestInfo":{"context":"_PARSE_.STOP.$service","operation_level":{"level":"SERVICE","cluster_name":"$CLUSTER_NAME","service_name":"$service"}},"Body":{"ServiceInfo":{"state":"INSTALLED"}}}' http://$HOST:8080/api/v1/clusters/$CLUSTER_NAME/services/$service
```

the problem is about the syntax - `_PARSE_.STOP.$service`

and we see that actually service value - `kafka` not set in - *PARSE*.STOP.$service

so ambri saw the name as - *PARSE*.STOP.$service and not *PARSE*.STOP.kafka

any idea how we can set the value `kafka` inside the `json` syntax?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expansion of variables inside single quotes in a command in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variables-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are not getting substituted when single quote type literals are used for strings so you need to break your string into parts to be able to insert some values into resulting string.

```sh
export service=kafka

curl -u admin:admin -i \
-H 'X-Requested-By: ambari' \
-X PUT \
-d '{"RequestInfo":{"context":"_PARSE_.STOP.'$service'","operation_level":{"level":"SERVICE","cluster_name":"'$CLUSTER_NAME'","service_name":"$service"}},"Body":{"ServiceInfo":{"state":"INSTALLED"}}}' \
http://$HOST:8080/api/v1/clusters/$CLUSTER_NAME/services/$service
```

here is an simplified example to make it clear:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
service=XXX

json='{"A":"$service"}'
echo "wrong JSON: $json"

json='{"A":"'$service'"}' #this string consist of 3 parts '{"A":"' + $service + '"}'
echo "good JSON: $json"
```

**output:**

wrong JSON: {"A":"$service"}

good JSON: {"A":"XXX"}