# How would I send a file's contents to update an existing Github Gist via Git bash?

Tags: git

I'm trying to remotely update an existing Github gist through Git bash, and I cannot find a way to upload a file's contents without manually declaring the contents inside of the command.

My goal is to take a file I have on my PC, and upload its contents to update a pre-existing Gist (the Gist ID which is mentioned in the latter text).

Here is an example Gist ID in the hope that it helps: 'c7alSToGZjxiMveTa2e6bzVvXJRqS09D'. For the sake of this discussion, the exact name of the file I am trying to upload is 'testingFile.txt', located at the file path 'C:\Users\username\Desktop', with the Gist file display name of 'monkey.txt'.

How would I make the "curl PATCH" command be able to execute such an upload/update procedure? I've tried the following code `curl -d '{"files":{"monkey.txt":{"content":"$chung"}}}' -u username:accessToken -X PATCH https://api.github.com/gists/{gist_id}`, where `$chung` was set equal to the file contents of "testingFile.txt". This exact code would just end up uploading the text "$chung" to the gist, instead of the variable's actual contents (which for this example, is `["WelcomeToTheJungle", "AmazonRainforest", "Brazil"]`. Any suggestions on how to do this are welcome, cheers!

**EDIT:** Github's API for this is- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/gists#update-a-gist

Comment: It doesn’t work because you enclosed the argument for `-d` in single quotes, anything inside single quotes are treated literally, so `$chung` won’t work

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [GitHub CLI `gh` 2.8.0 (Apr. 2022)](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.8.0):

> ### [Allow non-interactive gist file replacement](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/5408)
>
> Allows the overwriting of a gist file with a local replacement without any interactivity.
>
> The behavior change is that if the user specifies the gist file to edit using the `--filename` flag, then skip showing the continuation prompt of Submit/Cancel/Edit.
>
> It follows the same syntax as adding a file:
>
> ```sh
> # adding new file
> gh gist edit <gist-id> -a <gist-filename> <local-filename>
>
> # overwriting file
> gh gist edit <gist-id> -f <gist-filename> <local-filename>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curl -d '{"files":{"monkey.txt":{"content": '"$chung"'}}}' -u username:accessToken -X PATCH https://api.github.com/gists/{gist_id}
```

As a follow up to my comment I have a solution, you can do this `'literal'"$variable"'literal'` To have variables inside strings, **or just replace all your single quotes with double quotes**, then the `$chung` won’t be literal.

Reference:

- [Expansion of variables inside single quotes in a command in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variables-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash)