# What is the safest way to inject an outside variable into a Linux shell script that in turn executes code over SSH?

Tags: linux, shell

I need to write a Linux shell script that looks something like this -- it will be executed by a job-scheduling tool where ordinary end users can configure `$1` and `$2`:

```sh
SERVER=$1
OPTIONS=$2
ssh -t remote_user_name@$SERVER 'ksh -lc "remote_command_name $OPTIONS"'
```

Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variables-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash), I can see that I need to be careful how I write this to avoid "injection" issues.

*(Not to mention, being inside single quotes, I don't actually have $OPTIONS interpolating at this point.)*

In my case, acceptable options for `remote_command_name` are things like:

1. `--help`
2. `config_file_path_to_run_against`
3. `--verbose config_file_path_to_run_against`

I'm not really a Linux person -- how would I get $OPTIONS interpolating and, to the extent possible, minimize "injection" vulnerabilities?  *(Note that the scheduling tool's configuration panel is already behind a login-wall that, if breached, probably means someone is already running amok.  But to the extent possible, I'd like to avoid being the person who wrote something **new** for the scheduling tool that turns a phished user account into a lever to elevated wild privileges on the machines it schedules or that provides a handy privilege elevation lever for a malicious end user.)*

FWIW, it looks like the shell of choice on both machines defaults to `ksh`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so far, I've gotten this far -- interpolation is now working.

Is it ... safe-ish?

```sh
SERVER=$1
OPTIONS=$2
REMOTE_COMMAND_DBL_QUOT="\"remote_command_name $OPTIONS\""
LOCAL_COMMAND="ksh -lc $REMOTE_COMMAND_DBL_QUOT"

ssh -t remote_user_name@$SERVER $LOCAL_COMMAND
```