# Insert a variable between two "

Tags: shell

I am trying to run a curl command in linux

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"configuredLevel": "$LOGGINGLEVEL"}' ${i//$WORDTOREMOVE}
```

I wanted to insert the variable `LOGGINGLEVEL` in the payload but I am getting some error with this request.

When I change `"$LOGGINGLEVEL"` with some other value eg `"INFO"` I am not getting any errors

Is the correct method to insert a variable between two `"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expansion of variables inside single quotes in a command in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variables-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash)

Comment: Use a tool like `jq` to generate JSON, to ensure any values in the variable are properly escaped.

Comment: Try this `-d '{"configuredLevel": '"$LOGGINGLEVEL"'}'` to connect your parameter.