# Why bash script does not run well?

Tags: bash

I write a code in Bash script and the Linux does not run it correctly and printed character instead of character’s value.

Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). Please copy the console output and paste here

Comment: You want `$(ls)`, not `'ls'`. And then [Expansion of variables inside single quotes in a command in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variables-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash). Pretty basic stuff, perhaps a Bash/shell scripting tutorial would be a good start?

Comment: Also, [ParsingLs - Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [ShellCheck – shell script analysis tool](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: You are confusing the back-tick character `\`` with the single quote character `'`. In fact, because it is so easy to get wrong, the back-tick is archaic syntax. The modern equivalent is to enclose the command in `$( ... )`. For example: instead of `for LOOP in 'ls'`, use `for LOOP in $(ls)`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the confusion between backtick and `'`, you are also over-using the sub-shell syntax. You do not need to use `echo $(cat $LOOP)`. You can just run `cat $LOOP` directly.

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in $(ls); do
  echo "Here is ${file}:"
  cat ${FILE}
  echo ""
done
```

A couple of points of style as well:

1. Name your variables after the thing they represent. The loop is iterating over files in the current directory, so the name `FILE` is more descriptive than `LOOP`.
2. It is a good idea to get in the habit of enclosing your variable references in `${ ... }` instead of just prefixing them with `$`. In simple scripts like this, it does not make a difference, but when your scripts get more complicated, you can get into trouble when you do not clearly delineate variable names.