# concat a string variable in jq bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

here is my bash script
test.sh

```
host='select((.tag_name!="dev")
curl -H "Authorization: token <token>" https:<git release url> | jq -r  '[.[] | <iwant host variable placed here> ][0].assets[0].browser_download_url'
```

I want to do something like below

```
curl -H "Authorization: token <token>" https:<git release url>  | jq -r '[.[] | select(.tag_name=="dev" )][0].assets[0].browser_download_url'
```

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variables-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash e.g. `... | jq -r  '[.[] | '"$host"' ][0].assets[0].browser_download_url'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: **$(host)**

```
host='select(.tag_name=="dev")'
curl -H "Authorization: token <token>" https:<git release url> | jq -r  '[.[] | $(host) ][0].assets[0].browser_download_url'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
... | jq -r  '[.[] | '"$host"' ][0].assets[0].browser_download_url'
```