# Bash script echoes variable name instead of value

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a bash script that should edit xml file. It looks like this:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> <url>https://${site_url}</url> ...  ' > /var/www/$site_url/system_config/config.xml
```

As you can see I have a variable in this script `${site_url}`. The problem is that script writes variable's name in xml file, not value and it lookes like this `<url>https://${site_url}</url>` and should look like this: `<url>https://example.com</url>`. What's wrong? Rest of this script works great with this variable only `echo` doesn't work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables won't be expanded in single quote strings. Details can be found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13802438/6235550

You could try this:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> <url>https://'$site_url'</url> ...  ' > /var/www/$site_url/system_config/config.xml
```

Comment: Duplicative questions should be closed, not answered. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).