# I want to use 'sed' command (for example) that have two variables. One should be evaluated and other not

Tags: unix, csh

I want to use 'sed' command (for example) that have two variables. One should be evaluated and other not.

For example,
var1="should be evaluated"
var2="should not be evaluated"

```
echo "should be evaluated" | sed 's|${var1}|$var2|g'
```

I want to see: $var2 (not value)

How to do it ? My goal is to replace one string that I get as parameter to variable name.

The problem is that a double apostrophe (") evaluated the variable and a single spostrophe (') not.
And I can't understand how to use it in the same command.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: You can have single-quoted strings and double-quoted strings adjacent to each other (without any blanks between them). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13802438/2554472).

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `sed` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="should be evaluated"
var2="should not be evaluated"

echo "should be evaluated" | sed "s|${var1}|\$var2|g"
```

- use double quotes in the `sed` to variables are evaluated.
- but backslash `$var2` to it is not evaluated.  `\$var2` then becomes *the character $ followed by text var2*.