# How to Break Down and Quote Complex Command in Variable

Tags: bash, variables

I have written a few scripts at home but I now facing an issue with quoting in variables. I have read a number of post but the size of the command and how best to break it up is confusing me and I would really appreciate some advice.

The command I would like to execute is;

```
curl -sk -H "X-API-Key: THisIsAnExampleAPIKey " -X GET "https://127.0.0.1:8384/rest/stats/device" | jq '."THIS-IS-A-DEVICE-ID-QDGRSIO-NDOGYJB-2RV6RAW".lastSeen' | cut -d "T" -f 1 | tr -d '"'
```

Ideally I would like my script to be re-usable in that I could pass in the DEVICE ID string as an argurment.

Can someone point in the direction as to how best break up this command?

I have tried breaking up the command and the immediate issue is the jq command since the DEVICE ID needs to be quoted when run in the shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--arg varname "$value"` to pass variables from bash into jq, at which point they can be accessed with `$varname` inside literal jq code.

```
apikey='THisIsAnExampleAPIKe'
devid='HIS-IS-A-DEVICE-ID-QDGRSIO-NDOGYJB-2RV6RAW'
url='https://127.0.0.1:8384/rest/stats/device'

curl -sk -H "X-API-Key: $apikey " -X GET "$url" |
 jq -r --arg devid "$devid" '.[$devid].lastSeen | split("T")[0]'
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Charles-Duffy . You're answer is certainly the correct answer and whilst I am still grasping bash quoting I an fairly advanced in other areas of Linux and your answer was more aligned with the quality and polish I try take with my systems. I learned some really valuable t\hings here - thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are probably confused by the difference between double quotes (`"`) and single quotes (`'`).

`bash` does not do variable expansion between single quotes, but it does so between double quotes:

```
a=hoppa
echo '$a'
$a
echo "$a"
hoppa
```

If you want double quotes in a string with variables, precede those with a backslash:

```
echo "hoppa=\"$a\" as you see"
hoppa="hoppa" as you see
```

So, your `curl` and `jq` would become:

```
apikey='THisIsAnExampleAPIKe'
devid='HIS-IS-A-DEVICE-ID-QDGRSIO-NDOGYJB-2RV6RAW'
url='https://127.0.0.1:8384/rest/stats/device'

curl -sk -H "X-API-Key: $apikey " -X GET "$url" |
 jq ".\"$devid\".lastSeen" |
 cut -d "T" -f 1 |
 tr -d '"'
```

The object of this answer is to demonstrate quoting in `bash`, not to provide the best possible solution.  The linked answer in the closure will perhaps provide a better solution, but might leave the OP with the same confusion.

Comment: Boo, hiss re: substituting variables into jq code vs passing them out-of-band with `--arg` (which is jq's answer to `awk -v`)

Comment: Also, why use `tr` to take out the `"` s instead of using `jq -r` and getting the literal content without quotes/escaping added in the first place? Similarly, you could tell jq itself to truncate before the `T` and not need `cut`.

Comment: How does the linked answer provide an answer to the quoting-confusion of the OP? Because that was the question.  The `curl`-`jq` combination only served as an illustration of the OP's confusion. Yes, `jq` has many and, especially for novice scripters, incomprehensible options and features, that might shorten the pipeline.  But you cannot realistically expect someone that has still problems with `bash` quoting to fully appreciate the ins and outs of `jq`.

Comment: We have other Q&A entries for other cases. Showcasing bad jq practices (which remain bad practices when ported to other languages frequently invoked from bash -- I mentioned awk too) is not a way to teach good bash practices.

Comment: Yes, the OP asked a question with a title that's much more general than their actual use case -- but that title question is arguably too broad to be on topic. Narrower Q&A entries that cover the ground you're covering here _without_ showcasing bad practices include https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753, and others.

Comment: Thaks @LjmDullaart . I totally understand why you answered the way you did and seeing my example explained correctly helped my understanding - thank you. My surface level knowledge of bash quoting was blinding my understanding of the application of quoting and your explanation was really useful in that regard