bash api script doesn't recognize variables
I have following script to change the firewall rules of one of my cloud servers.
The variables API_TOKEN and FIREWALL_ID are converted, but PUBLIC_IP doesn't get converted - it stays PUBLIC_IP, not 1.1.1.1 for example.
PUBLIC_IP=$(dig +short txt ch whoami.cloudflare @1.0.0.1)
API_TOKEN="XXX"
FIREWALL_ID="YYY"

curl \
        -X POST \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer $API_TOKEN" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d '{"rules":[{"direction":"in","port":"80","protocol":"tcp","source_ips":[$PUBLIC_IP/32]},{"direction":"in","port":"443","protocol":"tcp","source_ips":["$PUBLIC_IP/32"]},{"direction":"in","port":"22","protocol":"tcp","source_ips":["$PUBLIC_IP/32"]},{"direction":"in","protocol":"icmp","source_ips":["$PUBLIC_IP/32"]}]}' \
        "https://api.hetzner.cloud/v1/firewalls/$FIREWALL_ID/actions/set_rules"

Any clue?
Thanks Chris

Variables inside single quotes don't expand. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variables-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash

And don't build JSON with string interpolation, use a tool that's specifically implemented to handle JSON, such as jq. Using string interpolation will fail as soon as you have quotes or other reserved characters in your values.

Also, the result from dig will have double-quotes around it, which will be treated as part of the value unless you remove them.
