# '$' in regexp in bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I really don't know what I'm doing.
In variable a, I want to find the first appearance of '$' after the first appearance of 'Bitcoin', and print everything after it until the first newline.
I have the following code:

```
a = 'something Bitcoin something againe $jjjkjk\n againe something'
if [[ $a =~ .*Bitcoin.*[\$](.*).* ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" 
else
echo "no"
fi
```

In this example I would like to get 'jjjkjk'. All I get is 'no'.
This code might be really flawed, I have no experience in this. I think tho the problem might be with the '$' sign. Please help!

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/pvPKSE. Note your `a` is not declared correctly, and there is no `$` inside it as it is interpolated. Also, you are trying to use a PCRE regex with Bash, it is not right. `.` here matches any char including newlines. `[\s\S]` matches ``\``, `s` or `S`.

Comment: Ty, this helps a lot. I edited the code, still ot good tho.(Did I edit it right at all?)

Comment: No, not right, your string has no newline.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a working version of your code:

```
a='something Bitcoin something againe $jjjkjk\n againe something'
r=".*Bitcoin.*[\$]([^\n]*).*"
if [[ $a =~ $r ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" 
else
echo "no"
fi
```

You need to find 'Bitcoin' then find a '$' after it, no matter what is between, so you should use `.*` operator, also when you want to capture some text until a specific char, the best way is using `[^]`(not) operator, in your case: `[^\n]` this means capture everything until `\n`.

Also you had an issue with your variable declaration. `a = "..."` is not valid, the spaces are waste. so the correct one is 'a=".."`.

Using double quotation is wrong too, this will replaces dollar sign with an empty variable ([evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9420853/3314232))

Comment: `[^\n]` matches any char but ``\`` and `n`. It does not match any char but a newline. Besides, `a='something Bitcoin something againe $jjjkjk\n againe something'` has no newline, either.

Comment: If `a` is `'something Bitcoin something $ stuff OP wants to capture $other stuff\n etc`, then matching after `Bitcoin` using `.*` will only match `other stuff`, because `.*` is "greedy" and will consume as much as possible. So perhaps use `[^\$]*` instead of `.*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I added the backslash to escape the `$` because he's defining the regex in a double-quoted string. And I'm not suggesting this one change by itself will fix the regex. Only that it will prevent greedily skipping over multiple `$` characters in the input.

Comment: Yes, but still it won't fix this approach. *`[^\n]` this means capture everything until `\n`* is a mistake.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If by "this approach", you mean Saeed's solution in general, then again, I didn't say it would fix the whole solution. My comment only concerns not using `.*` because it might skip over multiple `$` characters. If you're referring to my fix for that, then yes I think my approach would need an additional backslash to differentiate between the character `'$'` and the regex metacharacter `$` which represents the end of a line. But aside from the missing extra backslash, then yes, it does fix the problem of `.*` being too greedy.

Answer (score 2):

Properly handle newlines in bash with [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) -- <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> sequences become literal newlines.

```
a=$'something Bitcoin something againe $jjjkjk\n againe something'
regex=$'Bitcoin[^$]*[$]([^\n]+)'
[[ $a =~ $regex ]] && declare -p BASH_REMATCH
```

```
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH='([0]="Bitcoin something againe \$jjjkjk" [1]="jjjkjk")'
# .................................................................^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To verify the contents contain newlines:

```
$ printf '%s' "$regex" | od -c
0000000   B   i   t   c   o   i   n   [   ^   $   ]   *   [   $   ]   (
0000020   [   ^  \n   ]   +   )
0000026
```