# Expanding environment variables in the command part of a dvc run

Tags: dvc

**Summary**: I am trying to define a `dvc` step using `dvc-run` where the command depends on some environment variables (for instance `$HOME`). The problem is that when I'm defining the step on machine A, then the variable is expanded when stored in the `.dvc` file. In this case, it won't be possible to reproduce the step on machine B. Did I hit a limitation of `dvc`? If that's not the case, what's the right approach?

**More details**: I faced the issue when trying to define a step for which the command is a `docker run`. Say that:

- on machine A `myrepo` is located at `/Users/user/myrepo` and
- on machine B it is to be found at `/home/ubuntu/myrepo`.

Furthermore, assume I have a script `myrepo/script.R` which processes a data file to be found at `myrepo/data/mydata.txt`. Lastly, assume that my step's command is something like:

```
docker run -v $HOME/myrepo/:/prj/ my_docker_image /prj/script.R /prj/data/mydata.txt
```

If I'm running `dvc run -f step.dvc -d ... -d ... [cmd]` where `cmd` is the `docker` execution above, then in `step.dvc` the environment variable `$HOME` will be expanded. In this case, the step will be broken on machine B.

Comment: Hi! Try covering your command in single-quotes, so that your shell doesn't expand env vars right away. E.g. `dvc run -f step.dvc -d ... -d ... 'docker run -v $HOME/myrepo/:/prj/ my_docker_image /prj/script.R /prj/data/mydata.txt'.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the solution. I was close... I tried `"` :)

Comment: @RuslanKuprieiev I now realized what confused me... [`run.md#L29-L33`](https://github.com/iterative/dvc.org/blame/master/static/docs/commands-reference/run.md#L29-L33). Shouldn't `"` be replaced with `'` in the docs?

Comment: Good point! Created https://github.com/iterative/dvc.org/pull/498 for that.

Comment: @RuslanKuprieiev can you create an answer so that we can close this? :)

Comment: It's kind of more of a question about Shell than DVC, but probably a common concern for `dvc run` also. E.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840536/how-to-use-an-environment-variable-inside-a-quoted-string-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](https://dvc.org/doc/commands-reference/run):

> Use single quotes ' instead of " to wrap the command if there are environment variables in it, that you want to be evaluated dynamically. E.g. dvc run -d script.sh './myscript.sh $MYENVVAR'

Comment: @Dror Not really. Am I missing something?

Comment: I would like to add that using curly braces around your variable name (as supported by bash), does NOT work in a dvc.yaml file, so make sure to avoid braced variables.